# Why isn't my electromagnetic harvester working?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics

I'm trying to build an electromagnetic harvester for a high school project but am struggling to generate any power. The device is basically a beam that moves back and forth when you hit it, and a magnet is attached on both sides of the beam. As the beam flaps back and forth, it should follow the circular path of the coils, yet I've been having trouble developing any substantial voltage.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Previously, I had been able to generate about 5 mV with a series circuit of 4 coils of bare 22 gauge copper wire (see pic), but I realized I should have been using enameled magnet wire and made the switch (same gauge size of 22). However, the enameled coil generated even LESS voltage and barely registered on my oscilloscope. Was the 5 mV a fluke, or is something wrong with the magnet wire? Could the coil size be an issue? I've sanded the ends of the coil to remove the enamel (also, measured resistance of the coil is only 0.7 ohms).

Btw, the magnet I'm using is a N52 grade neodymium disk with a diameter of 7/8".

Answer (score 1):

check the twisted-together splices in the magnet wire. I suspect you have not stripped off the lacquer insulation there, and possibly also on the ends of the wire you are connecting to your voltmeter. this would prevent your device from working.